# android tab layout after login

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

how to make a tab after user login in my apps.i make session preference class.

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager); 
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);  

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new HomeFragment(), "Home");
    adapter.addFrag(new ContactFragment(), "Contact");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

new tab "Profile"

```
SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Profile"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter.addFrag(new ProfileFragment(), "Profile");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Profile"));
```

Comment: if (session.isLoggedIn()) {

Comment: Please add some description to your answer